# Как форматировать SSD в котором установлена Fedora с под установщика Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Нужно форматировать SSD, который находится в /dev/sda. 60Gb нужно выделить под Ubuntu, остальное оставить под Windows. Сейчас на этапе выбора разметки, но там такая каша твориться, не хочеться затронуть HDD.

Выполнение команды `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda` вернуло `/dev/sda is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!`

Comment: сначала надо разбить на разделы (как я понял, они вам требуются), а уже затем на разделе создавать файловую систему.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Мне сначала нужно уничтожить старые разделы на которых устанвлена Fedora

Comment: тем более. сначала удалите разделы, потом создайте, и лишь только затем создавайте на нужных разделах нужные файловые системы.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Ну вот, как мне удалить старые разделы?  ) У вопросе написал, что пытался форматнуть все сразу, но не вышло

Comment: в вопросе вы пытетесь создать файловую систему непосредственно на диске (sda — это диск. sda1 — первый раздел на нём, и т.д.), а не на разделе. технически это возможно, но вам же требуется иное: <здесь следует повтор текста предыдущего комментария>.

Comment: удаление и создание разделов осуществляется одной и той же программой — редактором разделов. их более чем достаточно. есть и с cli, есть и с gui.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Может подскажете конкретней, для этого и задал вопрос...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Я то пробую стандартный gparted...

Comment: ничем не хуже любых других. к слову: это gui к программе parted.

Comment: а вопрос, видимо, стоит переформулировать, потому что спрашиваете вы в нём совсем не о том же, что и в комментариях.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin При попытке "Delete" раздела http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/J6LM.png

Comment: @alexanderbarakin этот рвздел хочу удалить http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/J6LP.png

Comment: это не ошика, а предупреждение.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Не могу удалить этот раздел http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/J6LR.png. Ошибка конкретнее http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/J6LV.png

Comment: если у вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «задать вопрос» в правом верхнем углу страницы.